# Append Results from two queries and output as a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two queries that I have to run, I cannon join them But their resultant tables have the same structrure.

For example I have

```
select * from products where producttype=magazine

select * from products where producttype = book
```

I have to combine the result of these two queries, and then output it as one single result. I have to do this inside a stored procedure.

PS These are just examples I provided, i have a complex table structure. The main thing is I cannot join them.

Comment: removed tag stored procedures

Comment: See also [multiple queries with union and order by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685199/199364) - that is for `MySQL` but I think concept works on any `sql`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
select * from products where producttype=magazine
union
select * from products where producttype = book
```

Comment: +1 Keep in mind that `union` will remove duplicate entries from the two sets. If you can guarantee that the two sets are distinct, or you do not care about duplicates, then `union all` will perform better, especially as your result sets get larger.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just needed this.

Btw. to allow duplicate entries, you can add some artificial unique ID. This way in MySQL:

`select *, UUID() from products where producttype=magazine
union
select *, UUID() from products where producttype = book`

Comment: The statement "their resultant tables have the same structrure" indicates that queries are coming from two different tables. If that is the case, Union and Union All are the best choice.

Comment: Now what's difference between above query and the query --> select * from ( select * from products where producttype=magazine
union
select * from products where producttype = book).. I see that this take bit less time to run in terms of mili seconds.

Comment: forgetting the basics while building rockets. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I think that magazin and book are varchar values and not columns in your table

```
select * from products where producttype in ('magazine', 'book');
```

Comment: One other way to do this is to use the ANY function.


```SQL
select * from products where producttype  =  ANY(ARRAY ['magazine', 'book']);

```

Answer (score 9):

Or, just a single query...

```
select *  
   from products 
   where producttype = magazine
      or producttype = book
```