# Ordering by related to table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model (vehicle) related to other 2 models (car & bike). A car belongsTo a Vehicle as well as a bike. A vehicle hasOne car OR hasOne bike.

I want to sort all my vehicles randomly and first the bikes and then the cars. I mean first all the cars ordered randomly and then all the bikes ordered randomly.

I must do this in a paginate way, so it must be done in a single query.

The approximations I've done are the following: order by car_id (then the bikes come first) but the order is always the same, I need to add the random factor inside each group.

Any tip will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Union](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#unions) should work:

```
$cars = Vehicle::selectRaw('*, 1 as ob')->whereNotNull('car_id');
$bikes = Vehicle::selectRaw('*, 2 as ob')->whereNotNull('bike_id');

$vehicles = $cars->union($bikes)->orderByRaw('ob, RAND()')->paginate(10);
```

Read more about [order when using union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685199/1331425).