# How to search for data within the entire database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created 3 tables tbl1, tbl2 and tbl3  in one database (my_db).
My question is how can I search the data from those three tables in one search ?

My code.

```
<?php
    include('connect-db.php');
        include('sort.php');

$Search  = isset($_GET['Search'])  ? '%'.$_GET['Search' ].'%' : '' ;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3  where name  like '$Sea'");

?>
```

Comment: is there any relationship amongst tables?

Comment: use joins and search the required text from all the tables

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619090/append-results-from-two-queries-and-output-as-a-single-table

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

[Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) are used if each of those tables have a shared relationship with each other. For example, a user may have a profile and a list of documents published. This will output each table as additional columns in the result.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
  JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
  JOIN tbl3 ON tbl1.id=tbl3.id 
WHERE tbl1.name LIKE '$Sea'
```

If you want to add each table as extra rows in the result then you can use a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). You need to structure your results the same in all tables for this to work. For this reason, unions work best when your tables are very similar in structure. Keep in mind that union will remove duplicate entries from the two sets. If you can guarantee that the two sets are distinct, or you do not care about duplicates, then `union all` will perform better, especially as your result sets get larger.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.name LIKE '$Sea'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.name LIKE '$Sea'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl3.name LIKE '$Sea'
```

UPDATE:
Also, as others have mentioned, you are using deprecated mysql functions. Here is a sample of a better way to connect and use MYSQL:

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using PDO (which is more secure than the 
   older mysql libraries because it supports query parameters). */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Query example
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['id'].', '.$row['anotherfield'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Quest\Product\search.php on line 211

Comment: now it show the above error please guide me what should i do now ?

Comment: This means that there was an error in your SQL. Run the query from a SQL client first to make sure you have that part working.

Comment: Replace the '$Sea' part with an actual value in your SQL client.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to implement JOINS, while querying Database, to use JOINS the tables must have some kind of relationship between them.

So once you use JOINS in your query it would easy for you to get the results.