# Append a SELECT to another SELECT and then SELECT Unique items from that result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, append, unique

I am still new to SQL. I would like to take the results from both of these Selects and append one to the other, and then only select the Unique items from that result.

```
SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ',[FArticle no.],' - ',[Store ID],' - ',[base UOM]) FROM tblStock

SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ',[FArticleNumber], ' - ',[Store ID],' - ','EA')  FROM tblSales;
```

Comment: you should use union https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql

Comment: Just add `UNION` in between those 2, it will remove duplicates by itself, if you go with `UNION ALL` you will keep duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append Results from two queries and output as a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619090/append-results-from-two-queries-and-output-as-a-single-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ',[FArticle no.],' - ',[Store ID],' - ',[base UOM]) FROM tblStock
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ',[FArticleNumber], ' - ',[Store ID],' - ','EA')  FROM tblSales
```

Read here about `UNION` and `UNION ALL` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql

Comment: `and then only select the Unique items from that result.` : Change `UNION ALL` to just a `UNION` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am used to avoid duplicates in the base queries as UNION is more expensive than UNION ALL

Comment: @plaidDK as you can see, I changed the answer and added a reference to understand it. I pointed out why I automatically used the union all in a hurry ;)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. How do I close this Question? also new to SO.

Comment: Just mark an answer as correct: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. You don't close it, unless it is a duplicate or not really a question, opinion based and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `UNION`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ', [FArticle no.], ' - ', [Store ID], ' - ', [base UOM])
FROM tblStock
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('CSALES - PNP - ', [FArticleNumber], ' - ', [Store ID], ' - ', 'EA')
FROM tblSales;
```

`UNION` removes duplicates.

Comment: You missed the UNION.